# How to properly pronounce the diphthong in "found" in American English

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics

I hear American people say *found* as /faʊnd/. The /aʊ/ sound starts with [æ] (like in *cat*) and ends with [u] (ooh). However if I look up the word *found,* the pronunciation is shown as /faʊnd/ but is spoken as [fɑund] ("ah" sound like in car).

Which pronunciation is right, [fæund] or [fɑund]?

Comment: This type of question should have been solved by a dictionary. If you look online, like [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/found) they actually have audio of how it's said.

Comment: It's "faʊnd" as in pound, mound, sound, crowned, frowned. Not sure where you heard "fɑund", it might've been a thick southern accent or something.

Answer (score 4):

The initial sound of the diphthong in *found* is standardly described as in between the vowel sound of *cat* and the vowel sound of *car.* See [Pronunciation of the diphthongs /aʊ/ as in “owl” and /aɪ/ as in “why”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81779), [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288952/in-which-vowel-do-the-diphthongs-aʊ-and-aɪ-start](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288952/in-which-vowel-do-the-diphthongs-a%CA%8A-and-a%C9%AA-start)

That said, in my accent the starting point of the vowel in *found* /faʊnd/ sounds to me closer to the vowel of *fat* /fæt/ than the vowel of *fought* /fɑt/ (I won't compare to "cat" becuase that starts with a different consonant that might affect the vowel). When I try to pronounce /ɑʊ/ it sounds pretty foreign.

In other accents, however, the situation may be and probably is different.

Answer (score 0):

Produce /a/ as in the doctor saying  "say ahhh"…. followed by oo as in "soon". Be careful not to over emphasize the oo. The co-articulation (i.e., influence on each other will round and naturalize the production.